# Github repository is empty when rsync is used

Tags: github, ssh, github-actions, rsync

I have added workflow to github actions where i want to rsync files from repository to remote server

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy with rsync
        run: rsync -avuz --delete . ${{ secrets.USER }}@${{ secrets.HOST }}:~/App/MainPage/
```

rsync sends nothing because my repository in source folder is empty, **even though there are files in repo**.

[image]

i get this message

[image]

I know that rsync works, because if i change dir (eg ../../) files are being transferred to remote server and i can see them there.

[image]

Comment: Have you added https://github.com/actions/checkout?

Comment: @Clive yes, that was it, tysm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add checkout action to workflow .yaml file

```
...
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install SSH Key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
....
```